# How to find and mark duplicates in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have two ES indices which contain data about people (name, birth_date etc). There are people which are present in both indices, for example:

**index1**

| _id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| qqwew | demo | demo | 1998.10.10 |  |
| etroty | demo2 | demo2 | 1995.11.11 |  |
| werewr | demo3 | demo3 | 1997.09.09 |  |

**index2**

| _id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sdfll | demo514 | demo514 | 2001.11.04 |  |
| fdgdg | demo2 | demo2 | 1995.11.11 |  |
| sdfdfg | demo512 | demo512 | 2000.05.16 |  |

As you can see, this entry is contained in both indices (compared by first_name, last_name & birth_date):

| _id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *id is different* | demo2 | demo2 | 1995.11.11 |  |

I need to find such entries and add an additional field with unique id in it, so **index1** & **index2** should look like this afterwards:

**index1**

| _id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| qqwew | demo | demo | 1998.10.10 | null |
| etroty | demo2 | demo2 | 1995.11.11 | QWERTY |
| werewr | demo3 | demo3 | 1997.09.09 | null |

**index2**

| _id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sdfll | demo514 | demo514 | 2001.11.04 | null |
| fdgdg | demo2 | demo2 | 1995.11.11 | QWERTY |
| sdfdfg | demo512 | demo512 | 2000.05.16 | null |

My data comes as CSV files which are parsed & imported into ES (via Java). I'm not sure on which stage I should do things like this or whether it's even possible with ES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wondering how I solved this - I did not. The best solution is **hashing**, but it does not completely suit to my needs.